# Fastest way of swapping two different keys in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dict, where the key represents a number to be ordered, and the value represents the order it is currently in, starting at the zeroth index:

```
{4: 0, 3: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}
```

How do I make the above dict swap its key so that it becomes like something below?

```
{1: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 2: 3}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Also, what does "something like" mean? Is that the expected output or isn't it?

Comment: Apologies, when I meant like I meant that is the output. What I want is to swap the key '4' and key '1'. I hope this makes sense, if it doesn't I can try and clarify more

Comment: Why do you want to swap key 4 with key 1? What's the logic behind it?

Comment: Well originally it was an array, but I would like to order the dict so that I can compare the keys to the values. if the values in the dict are equal to key - 1, then its considered to be swapped. Its just a question that I'm trying to solve on hacker rank.

Comment: `d[1], d[4] = d[4], d[1]`? Why would a dict need to be ordered for you to compare its keys and values? If you want to compare it with another dict, shouldn't it be as easy as accessing the other's keys and values?

Comment: @zampoan it sounds like you could consider using a list instead of a dictionary. Then `enumerate(my_list)` yields tuples where the first element is the index (position) in the list and the second element is the value: that should alow you to do the comparison you describe.

Comment: Does the order of the dict items matter? If it does, then this sounds like a bad idea that you probably shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the values of the two keys can be done like any other variable swapping:

```
d = {4: 0, 3: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}

d[4],d[1] = d[1],d[4]

print(d)
{4: 2, 3: 1, 1: 0, 2: 3}
```

After that, if you want to reorder the keys in the dictionary, you'll need to rebuild it using a sort.  Dictionaries retain their key adding order but offer no manual control of the order beyond that:

```
d = dict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda kv:kv[1]))

print(d)

{1: 0, 3: 1, 4: 2, 2: 3}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using Python there's this clever trick called [dictionary comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension#:%7E:text=Now%2C%20let%27s%20create%20the%20dictionary%20in%20the%20above%20program%20using%20dictionary%20comprehension)

You could use it to make your code clean and readable:

```
swapped_dict = {v: k for k, v in original_dict.items()}
```

Comment: That would give `{0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 2}` which isn't OP's desired output.

Comment: I see, it's just a bad question. From other answers it's clear